# How to find out what causes user shell to be changed to /bin/false

Tags: ssh, bash, shell

I have the case when one of my users are getting login disabled automatically.

I was trying to find out what is causing this. Found that rkhunter app was monitoring changes in /etc/passwd and restoring saved version in case if change was detected.
Now I have removed rkhunter completelly. But case is still there.

I see in /var/log/secure the lines like
'change user xxx shell from /bin/bash to /bin/false'

And thats all what I have found. Obviously, there is some app that are runing usermod command to do that change.
But I unlikelly unable to find it.

Does anyone had such cases in experience? How can I find source of the issue?

Comment: What was the actual log entry?